# Add trend line for every facet using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, trendline

I have created a similar plot following the instructions from this link regarding the plot with facets:

[image: Scatterplot of mpg vs. hp for each combination of gears and cylinders]
<sub>(source: [statmethods.net](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/ggplotscatter.png))</sub>

I would like to add a trend line for every facet of the chart and also would like to arrange the facets for the y axis (3 gears, 4gears and 5 gears) manually. Same thing for x axis (4cyl, 6vyl and 8cyl) facets so they are arranged the way I want it rather than being sorted/arranged automatically.
I tried looking for a solution here in StackExchange and Googling around and found ways to add trendiness for charts that do not involve facets, but not how add trend lines for charts with multiple facets.

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a `geom_smooth()` layer? `ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm") + facet_grid(gear~cyl)` And if you want to change the order of the groups, create factors and put the levels in whatever order you want.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for the advise. Your code did the trick.